# MySQL seek-then-scan optimization for Limit Offset

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, backup

From the [mk-archiver](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-archiver.html#no_ascend) help, we can see there is an option to optimize "`seek-then-scan`". Any idea how do they do this?

What I'm really looking for is, if I do have a table with one PKey, and queries

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM tbl LIMIT 1,10;
SELECT col1,col2 FROM tbl LIMIT 11,20; ...

SELECT col1,col2 FROM tbl LIMIT m,n;
```

Any way to do this in an optimized way, given `m` and `n` are very large values and each select query is initiated in parallel from multiple machines? (will address host/network choking later)

How do others tackle the situation if the table doesn't have a PKey?

*Using MySQL

> The default ascending-index optimization causes mk-archiver to
>   optimize repeated SELECT queries so they seek into the index where the
>   previous query ended, then scan along it, rather than scanning from
>   the beginning of the table every time. This is enabled by default
>   because it is generally a good strategy for repeated accesses.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are playing directly with the index structures, not relying on SQL. Advantage of access to source code of MySQL. It should be possible to have such an option using SQL, per connection, but with multiple users connect through intermediate (web) servers would be more complicated, if at all possible.